# delete specific elements from list

Tags: list

First I select the group named hairSystem1Follicles and make a list of it
then I make an empty list with things to delete

```
cmds.select('hairSystem1Follicles',hi=1)
list=cmds.ls(sl=1)
listtodelete=[]
```

I have tried two things, but both are useless.
I would like it to isolate all the elements in the list with the name curve1 curve2 etc. not # the other things in the list which are named loftfolicle*
attempt 1

```
for e in list:
    if e=='curve*': #Find which ones are Write nodes
        listtodelete.append(e)
```

attempt 2

```
for e in list:
    if 'curve'+'*' in e:
        listtodelete.append(e)
```

neither seem to work out.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It looks like python.

Comment: e == "curve*" only checks for "curve*", its not regex, try e.startswith("curve"), if neccessary, try e.lower().startswith("curve")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how which functions you use to get your list (i would rename your list, because "list" is the typename of the built-in list), but if your list only contains strings, this code should work:

```
for e in myList: //renamed list
    if e.lower().startswith("curve"):
        listtodelete.append(e)
```

This code checks, if the lowercase version of e starts with "curve", so things like "curve2", "curve4", "CuRvEandsoOn" are appended to listtodelete. If there are any more conditions to check on e, let me know. By the way, if e is no string, maybe because you iterate a list of object, and you get "the name of e" (the actual string to check) by e.g. e.name(), just add this line of code at the beginning of your for loop:

```
e = e.name() //or something else, if e is no string, but e.name() is
```

Comment: ah, great thanks. It also needed to be converted to a string, but now it works like I needed it to.
    myList=cmds.ls(sl=1)
    listtodelete=[]
    for e in myList:
        if e.lower().startswith("curve"):
        listtodelete.append(str(e))
    cmds.delete(listtodelete)